# Android fastlane deployment with flavored applicationId

Tags: android, gradle, fastlane, fabric.io, fabric-beta

I have Fastlane set up to build variants of my app.  I have a Fabric Beta app for one of the variants set up and working for one of the variants, the original one.

Now that I've added another flavor with a different `applicationId`, and configured Fastlane to build that variant, I'm not seeing a new app created in Fabric.

What are the steps to create a new app in Fabric, with an existing app but a new `applicationId` per build variant?

Comment: So the fastlane part of the lane, building the app etc, all works as expected and produces the correct app with the right `applicationId`?

Comment: Yeah, the problem part was that Fabric plugin wasnt creating a new app unless I created an entirely new project with that applicationId